# Room Update the data only if it changed from the server

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a function which runs every 30 seconds, in which it fetches the latest data from the server and stores locally.

Currently, I'm deleting all the existing rows and reinserting all the data again, but I think this way is not the efficient one, I should be **updating** the data only if the local data and server data defers.

So how can I do that?

Here's what I'm doing:

DatabaseDao:

```
@Dao
public interface GeneralDatabaseDao {

@Query("DELETE FROM table_tables")
int deleteTables();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertRestaurantTablesData(TablesModel... TablesModels);
}
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<List<TablesModel>> getTablesData(int mLocationID) {
    mTablesList = new MutableLiveData<>();

    LiveData<TablesModel> mTablesData = mTableDataSource.getTablesData();

    Observer<TablesModel> mObserver = tableModels -> {
        mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {

            //Completed: delete old table data if there are conflicts.

            if (tableModels != null) {

                mDatabaseDao.deleteTables();

                mDatabaseDao.insertTablesFromServer(tableModels.getTables());

            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Nothing: ");
            }
        });
        Log.e("Handlers", "repository getTablesData");
    };

    if (!mTablesData.hasObservers()) {
        mTablesData.observeForever(mObserver);
    }

    return mDatabaseDao.getTablesData(mLocationID);
}
```

I know I need to compare all the local rows to the data which I got from the server and then update only changed data, But for that, I need to query local data and check row by row in a loop and then update. I'm fine with doing that but is there any other efficient way to that?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no alternative. Moreover, if you delete and insert again, you will activate the UI refresh each time. Since you used live data to update UI only when it is needed, you need to update the database only when it is strictly necessary.

With the code you write, each time you check web service, UI will be refresh. Better check each time if there are rows to change and modify them.

Comment: Okay I did it, and of course, it worked, but it's just it would be better if there is any method in room API, so it'd save a little development time :)